# How to plot multiple graphs with Plotly, where each plot is for a different (next) day?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I want to plot machine observation data by days separately,

so changes between Current, Temperature etc. can be seen by hour.

Basically I want one plot for each day. Thing is when I make too many of these Jupyter Notebook can't display each one of them and plotly gives error.

f_day --> first day

n_day --> next day

I think of using sub_plots with a shared y-axis but then I don't know how I can put different dates in x-axis

How can I make these with graph objects and sub_plots ? So therefore using only 1 figure object so plots doesn't crash.

Data looks like this

```
    ,ID,IOT_ID,DATE,Voltage,Current,Temperature,Noise,Humidity,Vibration,Open,Close
0,9466,5d36edfe125b874a36c6a210,2020-08-06 09:02:00,228.893,4.17,39.9817,73.1167,33.3133,2.05,T,F
1,9467,5d36edfe125b874a36c6a210,2020-08-06 09:03:00,228.168,4.13167,40.0317,69.65,33.265,2.03333,T,F
2,9468,5d36edfe125b874a36c6a210,2020-08-06 09:04:00,228.535,4.13,40.11,71.7,33.1717,2.08333,T,F
3,9469,5d36edfe125b874a36c6a210,2020-08-06 09:05:00,228.597,4.14,40.1683,71.95,33.0417,2.0666700000000002,T,F
4,9470,5d36edfe125b874a36c6a210,2020-08-06 09:06:00,228.405,4.13333,40.2317,71.2167,32.9933,2.0,T,F
```

Code with display error is this

```
f_day = pd.Timestamp('2020-08-06 00:00:00')

for day in range(days_between.days):

    
    n_day = f_day + pd.Timedelta('1 days')

    fig_df = df[(df["DATE"] >= f_day) & (df["DATE"] <= n_day) & (df["IOT_ID"] == iot_id)]

    fig_cn = px.scatter(
                        fig_df, x="DATE", y="Current", color="Noise", color_continuous_scale= "Sunset",
                        title= ("IoT " + iot_id + " " + str(f_day.date())),
                        range_color= (min_noise,max_noise)
                     )

    f_day = n_day

    fig_cn.show()
```

Comment: Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. Only plot images are okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### updated

The question was with respect to *plotly* not *matplotlib*. Same approach works.  Clearly axis and titles need some beautification

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.subplots
import plotly.express as px
import datetime as dt
import random

df = pd.DataFrame([{"DATE":d, "IOT_ID":random.randint(1,5), "Noise":random.uniform(0,1), "Current":random.uniform(15,25)}
             for d in pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,9,1), dt.datetime(2020,9,4,23,59), freq="15min")])

# get days to plot
days = df["DATE"].dt.floor("D").unique()
# create axis for each day
fig = plotly.subplots.make_subplots(len(days))

iot_id=3
for i,d in enumerate(days):
    # filter data and plot ....
    mask = (df["DATE"].dt.floor("D")==d)&(df["IOT_ID"]==iot_id)
    splt = px.scatter(df.loc[mask], x="DATE", y="Current", color="Noise", color_continuous_scale= "Sunset",
                        title= f"IoT ({iot_id}) Date:{pd.to_datetime(d).strftime('%d %b')}")
    # select_traces() returns a generator so turn it into a list and take first one
    fig.add_trace(list(splt.select_traces())[0], row=i+1, col=1)

fig.show()
```

[image]

It's simple - create the axis that you want to plot on first.  Then plot.  I've simulated your data as you didn't provide in your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import random

df = pd.DataFrame([{"DATE":d, "IOT_ID":random.randint(1,5), "Noise":random.uniform(0,1), "Current":random.uniform(15,25)}
             for d in pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,9,1), dt.datetime(2020,9,4,23,59), freq="15min")])


# get days to plot
days = df["DATE"].dt.floor("D").unique()
# create axis for each day
fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(days), figsize=[20,10],
                      sharey=True, sharex=False, gridspec_kw={"hspace":0.4})

iot_id=3
for i,d in enumerate(days):
    # filter data and plot ....
    df.loc[(df["DATE"].dt.floor("D")==d)&(df["IOT_ID"]==iot_id),].plot(kind="scatter", ax=ax[i], x="DATE", y="Current", c="Noise", 
                                              colormap= "turbo", title=f"IoT ({iot_id}) Date:{pd.to_datetime(d).strftime('%d %b')}")
    ax[i].set_xlabel("") # it's in the titles...
```

**output**
[image]

Comment: This is a matplotlib answer to a plotly question.

Comment: @vestland fair point misread.  The technique is equivalent.

Comment: Nice to know! Since answers under the "wrong" tag is actually allowed, I'd just like to let you know I'm not the downvoter even though I was the only one to leave a comment on this.

Comment: I get `---> 13     fig.add_trace(list(splt.select_traces())[0], row=i+1, col=1)

IndexError: list index out of range` when I run your code

Comment: ok - that code is exceptionally lazy ... not checking bounds  `if len(list(splt.select_traces())) > 0:
        fig.add_trace(list(splt.select_traces())[0], row=i+1, col=1)`
 should fix it.  I simulated by setting `iot_id` to a non existent one

Comment: FYI I was the downvoter, but seeing as you've changed the answer to Plotly to fit the question specifications, I have reversed my vote. Thanks!